# HABTM Cake php find

Tags: php, cakephp, associations, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have tables below with HABTM associations.

```
user, group , groups_users

group , project, projects_groups

public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
            'Group' =>
            array(
                    'className' => 'Group',
                    'joinTable' => 'groups_users',
                    'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
                    'associationForeignKey' => 'group_id',
                    'unique' => 'keepExisting',
                    'conditions' => '',
                    'fields' => '',
                    'order' => '',
                    'limit' => '',
                    'offset' => '',
                    'finderQuery' => ''
            )
    );
```

I am trying to get all users, as a list for checkboxes, that are on a project using project id using query below

```
$users = $this->User->Group->Project->find('list', 
            array(
                  'conditions' => array('Project.id' => $this->Session->read('Projectid'))
                  ,'contain' => array(
                          'User' => array( 'fields' => 'User.id', 'User.email') 
                    )
            )
        );
```

But error below

> Model "Project" is not associated with model "User"

I have actually tried different ways to get this working but cant seem to get it right, how can i achieve what i want. cheers

Comment: This can only be Done with joins lookup joins in the cake manual

Comment: $users = $this->User->Group->Project->find('list', 
            array(
                  'conditions' => array('Project.id' => $this->Session->read('Projectid'))
                  ,'contain' => array(
                        Group=>array(  'User' => array( 'fields' => 'User.id', 'User.email') ) 
                    )
            )
        );

Comment: I know not the best way, but what about trying a custom sql query ?

Comment: @Cakephp.Saint I tried that code, says `Model "User" is not associated with model "User"`

Comment: If the relationships are correctly defined.. then my code will work.. I think relationship problems in the mode file

Comment: Does your user table have a project_id foreign key ? or  is the relation User -> Group - > Project?

Comment: @JelleKeizer I have a projects_groups table , i have to use the three relations

Comment: @Cakephp.Saint What relationships would you suggest?

Comment: @Cakephp.Saint Isnt the problem with your query that you have the User in the model chain call, then you also have it in the contain?

Comment: I am in Users controller Fetching all data from Project table with group and user data

Answer (score 0):

I achieved what i wanted with joins , is there a way to do this by using model associations, instead of the manual joins option?

```
    $options['joins'] = array(
        array('table' => 'groups_users',
            'alias' => 'gu',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'gu.user_id = User.id',
             ) 
        ),
        array('table' => 'projectGroups',
            'alias' => 'pg',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
                'pg.group_id = gu.group_id',
             ) 
        )
    );

    $this->User->recursive = -1;
    $options['conditions'] = array(
                    'pg.project_id = ' =>  $this->Session->read('Projectid'),
                    'User.Active = ' => true  
    );
    $users = $this->User->find('list', $options);
```